# Unknown inflating error while calling Toast

Tags: android

I have a published app which got some strange user feedback. Accordingly with the stack trace, there was an inflating error while trying to call a `Toast` `show()` method. The stack is the following:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:457)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:247)
at my.app.name.Launcher$ActionDecider.onPostExecute(Launcher.java:155)
```

And on line 155 I have just a common call of the Toast's show():

```
Toast.makeText(LauncherAct.getContext(), "Some random string here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Does anybody have an idea of what it could be?

Comment: Seems like problem with the context in your asynctask. Do you have correct context? You can pass the context from activity to asynctask using the constructor for your asynctask. Then use the local variable in your asynctask class as your context.

Comment: No, my context is alright. It follows the suggestion of good practice defined on the Android's blog to avoid memory leaks (which is a static getContext method that returns a given Activity context). The method always return the context that is initialized on the Activity onCreate, so it should be ok...

Comment: @Alesqui Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Suddenly my Toast callings started to give this error `Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class`.I was calling my method again inside the same method until getting the desired gps values from network provider. When I remove recalling itself, the problem has gone. I did not get the relation between them but that worked.

```
public void getLocation()
{
    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        latitude = gps.latitude;
        longitude = gps.longitude;
        if((latitude < 0) || (longitude < 0))
        {
            Toast.makeText(CharityGPS.this, "Konumunuz saptanıyor lütfen bekleyiniz.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getLocation(); //recalling is here. when I remove it, problem has gone.
        }
        else
        {

           ...
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.